# Use gpx file to calculate distance from google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, distance

I want to calculate distance from a collection of geo coordinates. I have converted this to a GPX file and I am able to use in HERE Maps to calculate distance.

Now, I want to use this in Google Maps as per my customer requirement. Is there any option in Google Maps which accepts GPX file and return distance ? I have seen distancematrix option and believe this is in different format.

Comment: What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

There are some parts here. The calculation based on [Google Maps docs](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/maps-platform/how-calculate-distances-map-maps-javascript-api).

Notice that if you need only to calculate the distances, you don't need even google maps api. The calculation is based on the coordinates only.

#### Parse GPX file

GPX is basically an xml as well as html. So After you parse the content of the file using `window.DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/xml"));` you can use the DOM API (such as `querySelector`, `querySelectorAll` etc.) to retrieve all the `trkpt` element and extract their `lat` and `lon` values.

```js
const coords = Array.from(xml.querySelectorAll("trkpt")).map(
  element =>
    new google.maps.LatLng(
      Number(element.getAttribute("lat")),
      Number(element.getAttribute("lon"))
    )
);
```

I used `google.maps.LatLng` but you can store it in a plain object if you don't need it to interact with your map.

#### Calculate the distances

Iterate over the coordinates array and measure from one point to another.

```
function haversine_distance(coord1, coord2) {
  const R = 3958.8; // Radius of the Earth in miles
  const rlat1 = coord1.lat() * (Math.PI/180); // Convert degrees to radians
  const rlat2 = coord2.lat() * (Math.PI/180); // Convert degrees to radians
  const difflat = rlat2-rlat1; // Radian difference (latitudes)
  const difflon = (coord2.lng()-coord1.lng()) * (Math.PI/180); // Radian difference (longitudes)

  const d = 2 * R * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(Math.sin(difflat/2)*Math.sin(difflat/2)+Math.cos(rlat1)*Math.cos(rlat2)*Math.sin(difflon/2)*Math.sin(difflon/2)));
  return d;
}
```

Then you can the function to build the distances array

```js
const distances = coords.reduce((old, ne, index, original) => {
  if (index > 0) {
    old.push(haversine_distance(ne, original[index - 1]));
  }
  return old;
}, []);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-turing-tvhu1?file=/index.html